# How to delete table values by the date to compare with the current date in RoomData Base?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I need to delete past one week [ 7 days] data from the table. Hereby I am using  ROOM DATABASE.

```
SQLITE QUERY :  DELETE FROM NewEnquiry WHERE created_on < NOW() - INTERVAL -7 DAY

ROOM DATABASE QUERY : ?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **@Dao**

```
DELETE FROM NewEnquiry WHERE created_on < datetime('now', 'now', '-7 day')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Delete from NewEnquiry where id in(select id from NewEnquiry where created_on <= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )
```